# Why record is not being saved in database if i save data from static method in entity framework code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am newbie in Entity Framework code first approach. So please bear with me.

When i am calling **Add** method of **ProductRepository** class from MVC controller action method the data is not being updated in the database.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
public class FarmingDbContext: DbContext
{
    public FarmingDbContext():base("name=FarmerSiteConn"){}
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfileTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> ProductTable { get; set; }
}
public static class ProductRepository
{
    private static FarmingDbContext Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return new FarmingDbContext();
        }
    }

    public static void Add(Product product)
    {
        Repository.ProductTable.Add(product);
        Repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when i am replacing the above **Add** method as below then the data is being updated.

```
public static void Add(Product product)
{
    var Repository = new FarmingDbContext();
    Repository.ProductTable.Add(product);
    Repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

So what is the reason behind this problem would you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use repositories, that's what `DbSet` is about. Don't use static methods either. The way your code is written, it creates *two* repositories and never disposes them.

Comment: That `SaveChanges` in `Add` isn't going to add just one product either, it's going to persist all changes made to the DbContext until it's called. Just *don't* use repositories

Comment: Read [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to understand why those generic repositories are an *anti*pattern when used with any ORM, not just Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you are calling your Get (Repository) method, you are creating the DbContext. This means that you are providing a new instance every time (new connection essentially).

```
 private static FarmingDbContext Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return new FarmingDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Your call:

```
public static void Add(Product product)
{
    Repository.ProductTable.Add(product);
    Repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is doing:

```
(new FarmingDbContext()).Add(product);
(new FarmingDbContext()).SaveChanges();
```

You need to either update your Get method in your repo to return the same instance, or assign your initial instance to a variable. It's important to use the same context that you are adding to with the same context you are calling Save on.

Something like should work:

```
 public static void Add(Product product)
    {
        using (var repo = ProductRepository.Repository) 
        {
           repo.ProductTable.Add(product);
           repo.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Today i wasted a lot of time to understand that. I tried different combination to do that. But now l learnt the actual logic. Thanks a lot.